# Is there way to get or convert characters into svg path?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

In this picture is cursive Chinese character. There are lot of stroke order for normal Chinese characters.
Is there way to create this characters into individual stroke with path data like following.
[image]

For characters 我
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hanzi-writer-data@latest/%E6%88%91.json
From
https://hanziwriter.org/docs.html
Contain array of path with stroke details.

But how to create like this for cursive characters?

Comment: In that pictures there are only three stroke, 1. **/**  2.  **2**  3. **|** , so I just want to cut out in three pieces with three layers. An export path.

Comment: This shape is a very complex filled shape. I guess you want the character as stroke-only paths with varying widths with no fill just like a skilled artist would draw it . And you need automatic conversion, you are not interested in reading anything like "redraw it manually!". Right?

Comment: Cut out shapes, into three pieces

Comment: Can you draw with the pen the needed cutting lines? If yes, then use Path > Division. If you need some areas to 2 pieces split differently 2 copies of the same character and delete the extras.

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you have a character as a path, or a series of characters as one or more paths, you may select the character(s). On first click, you get the option to resize it from an edge or corner, with double click, you get the option to rotate the selection.

But what often is overseen, with the arrows not in the corner, but top or bottom in the center, you may skew the selection horizontally, which is in effect equivalent or close to using italic characters and useful, if your font does not include an italict face or didn't start as font at all, but maybe as bitmap or graph drawing.